# Magento lowercase all product titles

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

For some reason, my client added all products with capital titles in their Magento shop.
Now, I'm redesigning their webshop and I don't want to have capital titles.

I'm thinking about running a script, that's replacing all product titles for lowercase titles in the database. But, I'm afraid to ruin the database.

Does anybody know, how I can do this properly?

Comment: Lowercase or camelcase? On the website or in the database? Why you think that you would brake the DB?

Comment: If you are afraid to harm the DB, then: make a backup, see if you can restore from the backup, then do your changes inside the database. If anything explodes --- you have a backup (and you know it works)>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best way to do this (in my opinion) is to rewrite catalog/product model and add a method

```
<?php

    class Mynamespace_Module_Model_Product extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product {

        public function getName() {
            $name = parent::getName();
            return strtolower($name);
        }
}
```

or you simply can run this script:

```
UPDATE `catalog_product_entity_varchar` SET value=LOWER(value) 
where attribute_id = "XX"
```

where XX is your attribute ID for product entity; you will need to find correct ID for product name attribute;

**Remember to always BACKUP database before running any script**

Comment: The script is working, thnx! Is there also a camelcase solution?

Answer (score 1):

To change all products name(title as you called) you need  table `catalog_product_entity_varchar`.
In you model, or helper make some function like this to take all prioducts and using lopp change the name(title) and save it back.

```
public function renameProduct() {
    $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('name') //here you select all products name
                ));
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $product->setName(strtolower($product->getName())); //here you make lowercase you products name
        $product->save();//here you save to DataBase new names
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use strtolower(https://www.php.net/strtolower) or just in CSS the text-transform property(http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-transform.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can run this query to change case of Product title. Please take backup of Databse and also make sure about entity_type_id and attribute_id Value

`UPDATE catalog_product_entity_varchar SET value = LOWER(value) WHERE entity_type_id = '10' AND attribute_id = '96'`

I have tested this. its working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to correct the data, correct it in the db. Having a proper dev environment and up-to-date backups is a must anyway, so no need to be afraid of anything.

However, if you just want to fix the apperiance while leaving the data unchanged, consider using CSS to lowercase/camelcase the titles.

Answer (score 0):

You can also change product name case in the frontend phtml itself. For example, if you want to change the product name that appear in product view page, then go to app/design/frontend///template/catalog/product/view.phtml. There just edit the part which render the name of the product.

```
     <div class="product-name">
            <h1><?php echo strtolower($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name')) ?></h1>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not ideal but another simple option would be to use CSS.

Simply add a text-transform to your product title element.

So, assuming the product title is:

```
<h1 class="product-title">PRODUCT TITLE</h1>
```

For all lowercase simply add:

```
h1.product-title { text-transform: lowercase; }
```

Or you can capitalize every first letter with:

```
h1.product-title { text-transform: capitalize; }
```